# Need assistance in getting a Video Recording Component to work in my React App

Tags: reactjs, react-component, screen-recording

I'm trying to use [Video Recorder](https://openbase.com/js/use-screen-recorder/documentation)

In my react project. I'm using NPM install to and I've copied and pasted the USAGE documentation into a component file. I'm now trying to call that component on my App.js page and it will not work. Can someone explain the best way to get this working with maybe an example or screen recording of how to do so?
The content below is what I have put into my component: I then call the component  in my html of my APP.JS, shouldn't this work ?

```
import useScreenRecorder from "use-screen-recorder";

const Example = () => {
  const {
    blobUrl,
    pauseRecording,
    resetRecording,
    resumeRecording,
    startRecording,
    status,
    stopRecording,
  } = useScreenRecorder();

  return (
    <div>
      <video src={blobUrl} />

      <small>Status: {status}</small>

      <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
      <button onClick={pauseRecording}>Pause Recording</button>
      <button onClick={resumeRecording}>Resume Recording</button>
      <button onClick={resetRecording}>Reset Recording</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

Comment: "it will not work" is not enough to go by. What happens? What doesn't happen? What is the code you've used?

Comment: Please add your App.js code and provide some details on why it won't work. Are you getting an error message? Do you see any JavaScript errors in your browser console? Did you allow the component to record your screen and audio?

Comment: See revision above

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in a complete sentence. Don't make us guess what you want from two vague words. See [ask].